# How to I do a RESTFUL API via kubernetes service name

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have this method to get userinfo. I know that if I use a valid url 
`(i.e. http://url.to.access)`

my `getuserinfo()` is working.

Is there a way for me to use the kubernetes service name to call a GET request with my speing boot application? 
`(i.e. <pod-name>.<namespace>.svc)`

`userInfoUrl` comes from property.yaml:

```
  @Value("${auth.userinfoUrl}")
  private String userInfoUrl;
```

Method to get userinfo:

```
 public ResponseEntity<String> getUserInfo(String accessToken) {

    if (!StringUtils.hasText(accessToken)) {
      throw new InvalidAccessTokenException("Invalid accessToken.");
    }

    // Set authorization header with access token
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

    // Does url param tagging based on param given.
    UriComponentsBuilder builder =
        UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(userInfoUrl);

    // Call auth server to get user info.
    return restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a ClusterIP type [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/) in-front of the pods responsible for userinfo application. Then you can either use `servicename.namespacename.svc.cluster.local` from any namespace or just `servicename` from same namespace to access it in the spring boot application.

Comment: The class above is in my kubernetes pods. The one i am trying to access via service name is actually of a loadbalancer type. I tried with `servicename.namespacename.svc.cluster.local` but it wasnt able to resolve. Could i add a service in front of the loadbalancer to solve this issue?

Comment: add the service yaml and output of kubectl describe svc servicename in the question

Comment: Hi thanks. I solved the issue. In my service yaml, i forget to add in the port 80. i only have 443 in my service.